Ecobee saying 2 pieces of equipment running while Compressor is off
I have been having an issue with my A/C where the Ecobee Thermostat will say Equipment Running (2) but the Compressor will not be running. The only solution I have been able to find to correct it is to shut off both the main breakers for the Compressor and Air Handler.. Everything will work fine for a day or so, but then at some point I will notice it’s getting warmer in the house. I check the Ecobee and it will again say Equipment Running (2) but the Compressor is off. Reset Breakers AGAIN.. Works fine.. Day goes by.. Getting warm.. Check Ecobee.. (2).. Compressor off.. Recently had New compressor, Capacitor, Switcher Valve, and Contacts unit replaced As the Compressor burned out. The Compressor unit is a heat pump, and the air handler also has auxiliary heating.. Both are Trane.. Also replaced condensation pump thinking maybe the float switch shutoff was bad, but that didn’t fix the issue either.. What could be causing this?

Any thermostat or control circuitry running? what about fans running?

Sounds like you've thrown a LOT of money at some random guesses, thinking it's the equipment side that's failed when it could be that the thermostat has failed. Are there any diagnostics you can run on the Ecobee?

I don't know if any control circuitry is running.. And they weren't random guesses. The compressor went bad as verified by two separate A/C contractors. No diagnostics on the Ecobee I can run. Even now the Ecobee says Equipment Running (2) with the compressor breaker off..

Have you tried adjusting the thermostat? https://support.ecobee.com/s/articles/Threshold-settings-for-ecobee-thermostats

Equipment Running = sending a signal to make it work, assuming it does work. When you power cycle the condenser it works again. So then it's either the condenser or the T stat. Hook a stupid tstat to it for 3 days. If that works then it's not the condenser. If that doesn't work, call back whoever put it in to make it actually work. ... Is it a diff type of refrigerant, and if so they cleaned the lineset of oil, right? I would never fix a condenser other than a contacter, capacitor, and fan motor. When the compressor goes, that's new system time. You replaced everything except the coil... :(
